# Extra margin on top while Print Preview

Tags: css, salesforce, pdf-generation, apex

I am working with a visualforce page in salesforce , I have number of records that i want to be printed , i need 10 rows on page .I am using mod showing 10 records on page then page-break .I am wrapping content in a div

```
    <div style="!if( (mod(rowNum,10)==0),'page-break-after:always;','')}" class="wrap_me">
Content Here
    </div>
```

I am using the following Css

```
@page 
    {
        margin-top: 0.1mm;
        size: 457mm 329mm;                
    }
 @media print {            
         table#tabid{
            width:65%;
            height:50%;

        }       
    }
body{margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;}
```

I have tried alot of things to fix but the output is coming like this when i Print Preview : [Print_preview_screen](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B8vC14f_m3a-dm1oNWs5R1NLVFE/preview)

Not able to get it fixed.

Comment: Do you have applyHtmlTag="false" applyBodyTag="false" and have your <html> and <head> tag, it sometimes creates difference and makes various styles work correctly.